# Why doesn't the button call the function on click?

Tags: jquery, html

Okay, so I can't seem to figure out why nothing happens when I click on my button. I mean, I see nothing in the console.

My script:

```
function estimatedbill() {
    var objJSON = {
        seconds: seconds,
    }
    $.post('calculations.php', objJSON ).error(function() {
        console.log("this is the calculations part and it didn''t send it to calculations.php");
    }).success(function(data) {
        console.log("data gathered");
        //here output the result back
        $("p").text(data);
        console.log(seconds);
    });
}
```

And my button code is :

```
<table class="buttonTable">
    <tr>
        <td><button class="equiptButton"><img src="images/blackA.jpg"                      id="changePic" class="changePicA"/></button></td>
        <td id="counter"></td>
        <td id="bill"> <button id= "estimatedbill" onclick="estimatedbill">  Estimated bill:</button> <p>....</p></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What's the code of calculations.php?

Comment: Try to change: `onclick="estimatedbill"` to `onclick="estimatedbill()"`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, add parenthesis to the `onclick="estimatedbill"` to make the function call possible (change it to `onclick="estimatedbill()"`), then add a semicolon (`;`) at the end of the variable definition of `objJSON`, and finally your `seconds` tokens (in both `objJSON` definition and in the success function of jQuery post method) are also undefined (I just replaced them with `10` for debug purposes only!!, maybe you've eliminated it to be brief!)

Making these refinements will correct your code syntax and solves your issue, but you will need more work to make it *logically* correct!